# How can I display the three level div in turn by using z-index?

Tags: html, css

The html code is as follow:

```
<div class="first common">
    i am the first div.
    <div class="second common">
        i am the second div.
        <div class="third common">
            i am the third div.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.common {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
}
.first {
    background-color: #8EE5EE;
}
.second {
    background-color: #7A67EE;
}
.third {
    background-color: #0000AA;
}
```

The results are as follows
[image]

And now I want to put the first div in the front, the second div in the middle and the third div at the back (reverse) by using z-index if I could .
But I don't know how to do.

Comment: using js / jquery an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that html you cannot. A div that is a child of another div won't show behind it regardless of z-index. Restructure like this:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.common {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}

.first {
  background-color: #8EE5EE;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.second {
  background-color: #7A67EE;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.third {
  background-color: #0000AA;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="first common"></div>
  <div class="second common"></div>
  <div class="third common"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
I wrapped it in `wrapper` class. and reverse the left and top position of `common` class. no need to use `z-index`.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}

.common {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
}
.first {
    background-color: #0000AA;
}
.second {
    background-color: #7A67EE;
}
.third {
    background-color: #8EE5EE;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="first common">
    <div class="second common">
       <div class="third common">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He needs it other way around :) as in first div on top

Comment: I have edit the answer to meet the PO expectation and then you rollback to something he didn't ask for!

Comment: @ Mhd Alaa Alhaj. please read the description bellow the image of @legend. you updated the answer just like the result in the image.

Comment: my fault, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="common">
    <div class="first">i am the first div.</div>
    <div class="second">i am the second div.</div>
    <div class="third">i am the third div.</div> 
</div>



.common {
position: relative;
color: #fff;
}

.first {
position: absolute;
background-color: #8EE5EE;
z-index:1;
left:50px;
top:50px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

.second {
background-color: #7A67EE;
position: absolute;
z-index:2;
width:200px;
height:200px;
left:100px;
top:100px;
}

.third {
background-color: #0000AA;
position: absolute;
z-index:3;
left:150px;
top:150px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```